# SelectPDF ConvertHtmlString method truncates PDF

Tags: webforms, pdf-generation, selectpdf

I'm trying to use SelectPDF library in my .NET Web Forms project to generate PDF from the HTML string and write everything to the Stream.

The problem is that when I'm trying to generate that PDF I get the truncated file.

It works fine on the official demo when I put my HTML string there:
https://selectpdf.com

But it doesn't work in other demo:
https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/demo/convert-html-code-to-pdf.aspx

My code:
[image]

Do someone has any ideas on how that would be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SelectPdf **community edition**, there is a **limitation of 5 pages** in the free version ([SelectPdf community edition](http://selectpdf.com/community-edition/) )

There are [commercial versions](https://selectpdf.com/pricing/) of SelectPdf but they are not free.